# Connecting Windows 8 applications with Apache Server : (Background transfers in Windows 8)

Tags: php, windows, web-services, apache, upload

I have some problems during the upload of file on windows store application. I got Status 200, but when I check the server there's no file uploaded..I'm using apache server
I've checked the Sample of Microsoft [Background Transfer sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/) but it work with a ASP .Net server.

any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I need to upload one single file at a time, It works for me, let me know:

**upload.php:**

```
<?php
    $target = "data/"; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']) ; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } 
    else {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }       
?>
```

**C# code:**

```
    private async void StartMultipartUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(serverAddressField.Text.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Invalid URI.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Verify that we are currently not snapped, or that we can unsnap to open the picker.
        if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.Snapped && !ApplicationView.TryUnsnap())
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("File picker cannot be opened in snapped mode. Please unsnap first.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

        if (files.Count == 0)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("No file selected.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        List<BackgroundTransferContentPart> parts = new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            BackgroundTransferContentPart part = new BackgroundTransferContentPart("Filename", files[i].Name);
            part.SetFile(files[i]);
            parts.Add(part);
        }

        BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
        UploadOperation upload = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(uri, parts);

        String fileNames = files[0].Name;
        for (int i = 1; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            fileNames += ", " + files[i].Name;
        }

        Log(String.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}, {2}", fileNames, uri.AbsoluteUri, upload.Guid));

        // Attach progress and completion handlers.
        await HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);
    }
```

I used the same code of The SDK sample. *data/* folder is in the same folder of **upload.php** and my Uri is `http://mySite/myApp/upload.php`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a full solution. Basically you need to upload as **multipart** on your SDK Samples ( doesn't matter if it is C# or C++ ) and the key is to the php file. Here is my PHP file that processes all of the selected files. Works as a charm! Also if you get error 1 it means that in your php.ini the maximum file upload size is too small! So look out for that too. Hope it helps, it surely took me some effort to get this done.

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

foreach ($_FILES as $name) {
    if ($_FILES[$name]["error"] > 0){
        fwrite($fh, "Error: " . $_FILES[$name]['error'] . " on file: " . $_FILES[$name]['name']); // log the error
    }
    $target = "data/"; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES[$name]['name']) ; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES[$name]['name']). " has been uploaded"; // succes, do whatever you want
    } 
    else {
        fwrite($fh, "File movement error on file: " . $_FILES[$name]['name']); // log the error
    }       
}

fclose($fh);
```

?>